# Leaving a girl for the sake of allah

Tags: relationships

I met an atheist girl online about 2 months playing video games and we got along pretty well very quickly. Quite quickly the situation got seriously and we had thoughts about meeting up (she is in another country). This is when I brought up things like religion and parents as I saw this going into a more serious direction. She said that she was willing to learn about the religion. She even bought an English translated Quran and asked me questions about it here and there. Despite her willingness to commit, I knew that we had to essentially ‘date’ beforehand. I knew that this is forbidden and even if I tried to keep it halal, I had a feeling it would fall into haram at some point.
I would need to date her for a couple of years as I’m not ready nor is she ready to marry. Then of course this wouldn’t work without ever planning a meet up.

I like her a lot. The talks we have are amazing. We had plan to meet up but I left before we ever did. I told her that it is against my religion and called it quits before anything major happened.

There is also the less major issue which is parents. She is currently atheist but has looked into religion before. There is also an ethic difference which I’m sure my parents won’t be happy about. I would like their consent with the person i do end up marrying.

Did i do the wrong thing? She was willing to learn and become Muslim. My biggest concern is that I just won’t meet anyone that I get along with like I do with her. Was she written for me? Or was it a test from Allah?

Answer (score 0):

No bro, you aren't going to convert someone who doesn't believe in God into the deen with the power of your love. If she is interesting in coming to faith in her Lord there are plenty of resources for her as well as Muslim women. You aren't needed for that purpose and it is highly likely she would for the sake of love, "say what needs to be said" to make what she feels matters more work out. It was a test, Alhamdulillah you past, don't go to the gradebook and burn the papers now, Allah doesn't need you to guide her at all He is perfectly capable of using appropriate means for that. You have done well.